# Increase number of results for Wikidata query with MWAPI

Tags: sparql, wikidata, mediawiki-api

When including MWAPI in a Wikidata SPARQL query, the maximum number of items in a result set is always 50.

This is an example query:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
 SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
   wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
   mwapi:search "York"; 
   mwapi:language "en".
   ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
 }  
 SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}
```

Setting `wikibase:limit` to a higher value, e.g. 100 doesn't have any effect; the limit stays at 50.

How can I obtain more than 50 items from this kind of query?

Comment: The reason is that EntitySearch on Wikidata is limited to max 50 results: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T141620